# Is there any difference between using synonyms_path and using synonyms when specifying synonym filter for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

In term of performance, is there any difference between using synonyms_path and using synonyms when specifying synonym filter for Elasticsearch ? Please refer to the images for example. Note that in my ES cluster, there are many indices that will make use of this same synonym filter.

[image: Using synonyms_path]

[image: Using synonyms]

I am asking this question, because apparently AWS ES does not allow one to upload a file directly to the cluster. Therefore, I need to upload the synonym data by using the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have a choice then since you cannot use a synonyms file. Your only choice is to provide all the synonyms in the index settings.

Code-wise, whether the synonyms are read from a string or from a file, it makes [almost no difference](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/04e07bcdb69a55d3a58e14ca8b6a92e62b47db1d/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/SynonymTokenFilterFactory.java#L51-L59). The only difference will be that all the  synonyms will be stored in all the indices that need them, so that boils down to wasting a bit of storage space, but that's negligible (of course it depends how many synonyms you have, i.e. a few hundreds or many thousands).

What hurts more is that if you need to modify the synonyms list, you'll need to modify all your indices, instead of just a single file.