# What are the downsides of specifying synonyms directly in config instead of using synonyms_path

Tags: elasticsearch

I have around 440 kB of text files with Elastic Search synonyms.

For the moment, these synonyms are simply placed on every node's disk, and I use the configuration property `synonyms_path`.

Something like this (from the docs)

```
{
  "filter" : {
    "synonym" : {
      "type" : "synonym",
       "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

As these synonyms are regularly updated, it would be simpler to declare them directly in the filter configuration of each index (see the example)

```
{
  "filter" : {
    "synonym" : {
      "type" : "synonym",
       "synonyms" : [
         "i-pod, i pod => ipod",
         "universe, cosmos"
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

But [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) seems to discourage of doing like this:

> However, it is recommended to define large synonyms set in a file using synonyms_path, because specifying them inline increases cluster size unnecessarily.

So I have two questions:

1. How large is large, when specifying synonyms directly in the configuration?
2. What are the downsides of doing like this with *large* definitions. Specifically, what does it mean to increase the **cluster size**?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480527/is-there-any-difference-between-using-synonyms-path-and-using-synonyms-when-spec/41480615#41480615 Also see this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/synonyms-path-vs-inline-array/57948

Comment: Thanks. It helps but it's still not precise enough.

Comment: As explained in the second thread I linked to, if you use the inline `synonyms` approach, the synonyms will be stored once in the mapping (= cluster state) + another time in memory. Whereas when using the `synonyms_path` the synonyms won't clutter the mapping and will only be present in memory.

Comment: Is there an issue to add 440k to the mapping?

Comment: Well, as the mapping is stored on each shard, for a single index with 5 shards and 1 replica, those 440 KB will increase the cluster state space by 4.4 MB and in addition to the 4.4 MB (-ish) that they will take in memory anyway. It might not be much, but as you struggle to save memory you'll see those MB become important.