# AWS Elasticsearch synonyms using file

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add synonyms to elastic search as show in this link using a file but it gives me the following error https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

```
error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: ],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"IOException while reading synonyms_path_path:  (No such file or directory)"}},"status":400}
```

My mapping code looks like this and synonyms.txt is within the same folder (same level):

```
'settings': {
            'analysis': {
                'filter': {
                    'english_stemmer': {
                        'type': 'stemmer',
                        'language': 'english'
                    },
                    'english_possessive_stemmer': {
                        'type': 'stemmer',
                        'language': 'possessive_english'
                    },
                    'my_synonyms': {
                        'type': 'synonym',
                        'synonyms_path' : 'synonyms.txt'                        
                    }
                },
                'analyzer': {
                    'my_analyzer': {
                        'tokenizer': 'standard',
                        'filter': [
                            'english_possessive_stemmer',
                            'lowercase',
                            'my_synonyms',
                            'english_stemmer'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'mappings' : ...
```

Comment: How did you get stemmer to work-I am getting a{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":[indices:admin/create]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.filter.english_stemmer.language] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.filter.english_stemmer.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}]},

Answer (score 4):

Actually your problem is that you apparently can't submit a synonyms file to AWS and the only way you can do to use synonyms with this configuration is to upload synonyms via API following:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

which is not useful for a great number of synonyms.

See this other answer to a similar question for reference:

[Is there any difference between using synonyms_path and using synonyms when specifying synonym filter for Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480527/is-there-any-difference-between-using-synonyms-path-and-using-synonyms-when-spec)

and this taken directly from AWS forum:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=679800

And btw, the path actually should be analysis/synonyms.txt, but again, only if you were able to upload the synonyms file to AWS.

Comment: "can't submit a synonyms file to AWS" true thats the main issue. any idea of what would be a better way to upload a big chunk of synonyms?

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch is expecting to receive relative path to synonyms.txt starting from the config location. For example, if your synonyms.txt is located at `config/settings/synonyms.txt` the correct path is `"settings/synonyms.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

With support for custom dictionaries, Amazon Elasticsearch Service can now import your dictionary files from Amazon S3 and make them available to be associated with your Amazon Elasticsearch Service domain(s) as needed. Custom dictionary support is available for all versions of Elasticsearch on Amazon Elasticsearch Service. To learn more, see the documentation

[documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/custom-packages.html)