# indexing synonyms in ElasticSearch Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

### Problem description

I want to run a query string like this for example :

```
{"query": {
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["description"],
        "query" : "illegal~"
        }
     }
 }
```

I have a side synonyms.txt file that contains synonyms :

```
illegal, banned, criminal, illegitimate, illicit, irregular, outlawed, prohibited
otherWord, synonym1, synonym2...
```

I want to find all elements having any one of these synonyms.

### What I tried

First I want to index those synonyms in my ES database.

I tried to run this query with `curl` :

```
curl -X PUT "https://instanceAdress.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console/sources" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
"settings": {
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path" : "synonyms.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
'
```

but it doesn't work `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}`

I then need to change my query so that it takes into account the synonyms but I have no idea how.

### So my questions are :

- How can I index my synonyms ?
- How can I change my query so that it does the query for all synonyms ?
- Is there any way to index them in Python ?

### example of a get query using Python Elasticsearch

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['fullAdress.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io'],
    http_auth=('login', 'password'),
    scheme="https",
    port=9243,
)
es.get(index="sources", doc_type='rcp', id="301495")
```

Comment: Without specifying any path, your synonym file will be located in the config path /etc/elasticsearch/ . Where have you put your synonim file?

Comment: you can't do that in aws, please read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433446/aws-elasticsearch-synonyms-using-file

Comment: I have put the file in the directory in which I run my `curl` or my python code. 
I can't upload a file in AWS ? Is there any way around to force it ?

Comment: I don't know, looking on the internet it seems that you cannot, but i have never used ES on AWS. Maybe someone knows that situation better than me

Answer (score 0):

You can index using synonyms with Python by:
First, create a token filter:

```py
synonyms_token_filter = token_filter(
  'synonyms_token_filter',     # Any name for the filter
  'synonym',                   # Synonym filter type
  synonyms=your_synonyms       # Synonyms mapping will be inlined
)
```

And then create an analyzer:

```py
custom_analyzer = analyzer(
  'custom_analyzer',
  tokenizer='standard',
  filter=[
    'lowercase',
    synonyms_token_filter
  ])
```

There's also a package for this: https://github.com/agora-team/elasticsearch-synonyms